# How create react component with .tsx extension using react-create command

Tags: reactjs

Is this possible to create a component using React cli with .tsx extension. I have used **react-create component line-chart --jsx** for creating .jsx extension. Is there any React cli to create .tsx extension?

Comment: maybe this module can help https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grabantot/react-cli.
It supports custom templates. Send me a message if something is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript

This comment will create a React-Typescript project